# I can't show section in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a hidden section `("secundaria")` and i want to show it from a from out of the section with js. The section and its css is:

```
<section id="secundaria">
    <!--Formulario 2-->
        <h3>Nuevo pedido</h3>

         <form id="formulario_secundario">
                Nombre:
                <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="" />
                <br/>
                Fecha de cierre:
                <input type="text" name="Fecha_cierre" value="" />
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" name="aceptar" onclick="validar_rellenar(this.form)" />
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar">
            </form>

        </section>
```

And its css:

```
section#secundaria{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

I want to show it from this form with this function:

```
<form id="nuevo_form">
    Envio:
    <input type="text" name="envio" value="" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="nuevo" value="" onclick = "nuevo_formulario()">
</form>

<script>
    function nuevo_formulario(){
        console.log(document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility);
        document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log(document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility);
        document.getElementById("nuevo_form").reset();
    }
</script>
```

It's for class, so my teachers want the function and the section inside another section and the form outside. Thanks.

Comment: Try using type="button" instead of "submit" in the nuevo_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. The problem is that `input` of type `submit` will implicitly send the form, causing a page reload. Change to `type="button"` and everything works correctly.

```js
function nuevo_formulario() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility);
  document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility = "visible";
  console.log(document.getElementById("secundaria").style.visibility);
  document.getElementById("nuevo_form").reset();
}
```

```css
#secundaria {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="secundaria">
  <!--Formulario 2-->
  <h3>Nuevo pedido</h3>

  <form id="formulario_secundario">
    Nombre:
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="" />
    <br/>Fecha de cierre:
    <input type="text" name="Fecha_cierre" value="" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" name="aceptar" onclick="validar_rellenar(this.form)" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar">
  </form>

</section>

<form id="nuevo_form">
  Envio:
  <input type="text" name="envio" value="" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="nuevo" value="" onclick="nuevo_formulario()">
</form>
```

Comment: Or use `return false;` inside that function.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal there are other options, but I believe the best is changing the button type.

Comment: So, I used `OR` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjwon1sy/

Simply change the input `input type="button"`